# Design pattern for if else api structure

Tags: php

I have a central point where requests come in with a GET var 'service', and 'action' and maybe some POST data.

This is how my api.php looks now:

```
<?php

$service_name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'service');

if($service_name == 'training') {
    require_once('../service/TrainingService.php');
    $service = new RegisterService();
}
elseif ($service_name == 'mail') {
    require_once('../service/MailService.php.php');
    $service = new MailService();
}

$service->init();
```

Is there a more cleaner way of doing this? Maybe a fancy design pattern? I can image that this if else structure would get huge.

**Update:**

I like Marc B his solution. This is my version of it. Idea's for a better approach are always welcome... maybe loading the available classes from an XML config file?

```
<?php

$services = array(
    'mail' => 'MailService.php',
    'training' => 'TrainingService.php'
);

$service_object = null;
$service_name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'service');

if (array_key_exists($service_name, $services)) {

    require_once('../service/' . $services[$service_name]);

    $class_name = ucfirst($service_name) . 'Service';
    $service_object = new $class_name();

    if($service_object != null && is_subclass_of($service_object, 'Service')) {
        $service_object->init();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: A shorter solution would be to make some kind of auto resolver that would construct the name of the file and construct the object based on the service_name. This would require you to keep consistent file names and class names. Definitely a shorter way of doing it. If you don't want to do that a switch statement would be better than a large if tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lookup array?

```
$services = array
  // 'name' => 'script file'
  'mail' => 'MailService.php',
  'training' => 'TrainingService.php'
);

if (array_key_exists($service_name, $services)) {
    require_once('../service/' . $services[$service_name]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a framework such as Flight. Flight (and others) have the ability for you to define routes. So using your example:

```
Flight::route('POST /training', function(){
    ... code for POST to /training.
});

Flight::route ('/mail', function(){
    ... do something with either GET, POST, etc.

}
Flight::start();
```